# Show all records in a database table rather than individual records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm pretty new to rails. I'm learning how to pass database queries to json to render them in a view.

I would like to perform a simple one table query (table is called `user` `name:string` `id:integer`) which is performed in the model and passed to the controller and then to `index.json.jbuilder` to `index.html.erb.`

The problem is that when I call

`blabla/index.json` I get an empty array but when I call `blabla/1.json` I get the data of user 1, but I want to get ***all*** the users.

I am aware there are easier ways to do this but this is how I would like to do this. How can I avoid the need for passing the user_id to get the records?

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.feed
"SELECT * FROM User"
end
 end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
   def index
     @users = User.feed
   end
```

**index.json.jbuilder**

```
 json.extract! @user, :id, :name, :created_at, :updated_at
```

**index.html.erb**

```
 <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
 <h1>Listing Users</h1>
 <table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th colspan="3"></th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= user.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 <br>
 <%= link_to 'New User', new_user_path %>
```

Comment: Just declaring a variable to pass to json. Is that not correct?

Comment: where is your index method?

Comment: the controller show was a typo. Now corrected. Same problem though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def index
  @users = User.get_all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render json: @users}
  end
end
```

in user.rb

```
def self.get_all
  User.all
end
```

Comment: @Sebastian Zeki, Your `User.feed` method is just returning the string `"SELECT * FROM User"` - that doesn't evaluate in any way to an actual DB query. `User.all` as @user123 writes is what fetches the entire `users` table, then `render json: @users` returns it to the browser as JSON. Check out [ActiveRecord Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html)

Comment: Thanks but specifically wanted a model based answer as per original question. I'm trying to figure out how the model communicates with the controller really so that I can get all the results from a model query

Comment: @Sebastian Zeki No need of it. If something that will be used many times that you can use in model. But it is not necessary that you should write each query in model

Comment: Hi @Kristján I get what User.all does but Im trying to figure how to I can write more complex queries- skinny controller fat model and all that. So although User.all in the controller may be great for this very specific situation I'd like to know how to pass a model query to a controller in future as well. So I guess if Im just returning a string then how should I phrase the model query?

Comment: Although now i get ActionController::UnknownFormat in UsersController#index

Comment: I tried it but I still get the same error. It highlights the line respond_to do |format| and says ActionController::UnknownFormat in UsersController#index

Comment: have you write users_path(format:  "json") from where you calling index method of users_controller?

Comment: I have added the view where it should show the data I guess

Comment: Where do I put the users_path(format:"json")? Is that the update you are referring to?

Comment: from which view you are calling index method?

Comment: Im calling it from the index view I think. My routes.rb file says Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :users
end          and I am calling blabla/users/index

Comment: @SebastianZeki If you're using `resources :users` sending a GET request to `blabla/users/` directs you to the index, not `blabla/users/index` Check `localhost:3000/rails/info/routes` and see what the path, verb combinations look like.

Comment: I was trying to ask you that from where you requesting users' index method as json

Answer (score 0):

You can use user123's answer and probably should because the ORM can become super powerful when tied with ACL gems, caching, etc.  But you can also write more complex queries if you need to.  Here is an example of a more complex select users by distance from latitude and longitude using a [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) (you can also use in a function):

```
scope :near, -> (lat, lng, distance) {
  origin_lat = lat / 180 * Math::PI
  origin_lng = lng / 180 * Math::PI

  select("users.*")
  .select("(ACOS(COS(%{lat})*COS(%{lng})*COS(RADIANS(users.latitude))*COS(RADIANS(users.longitude))+
      COS(%{lat})*SIN(%{lng})*COS(RADIANS(users.latitude))*SIN(RADIANS(users.longitude))+
      SIN(%{lat})*SIN(RADIANS(users.latitude)))*3963) AS distance" % [ lat: origin_lat, lng: origin_lng, distance: distance ])
  .where(["(ACOS(COS(:lat)*COS(:lng)*COS(RADIANS(users.latitude))*COS(RADIANS(users.longitude))+
      COS(:lat)*SIN(:lng)*COS(RADIANS(users.latitude))*SIN(RADIANS(users.longitude))+
      SIN(:lat)*SIN(RADIANS(users.latitude)))*3963) <= :distance", lat: origin_lat, lng: origin_lng, distance: distance])
  .order('distance DESC')
}
```

Where you would then call it like `User.near(lat, lng, distance)` and it will return all the instances that are within a certain distance.

When it comes down to it, its just a matter of knowing where to place the strings within Rails' [query builder](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).